# Creating a graph of a scatterplot from a tuple of tuples

Tags: python

The second function will have you create an ASCII graph of a scatter plot, called
scatterPlot. If you are unsure about what a scatterplot is or how it works, please refer to
this website (https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/scatter-xy-plots.html). You will be given
a list of points, as a list of tuples. Each tuple contains (x,y,char), where x is the x dimension
of the point, y is the y dimension of the point, and char is the character that the point
should appear on the graph. Your job will be to figure out how to draw the grid, where
each point should appears where it’s x and y coordinates are. Each x and y coordinates
are going to be an integer values. To do so, you will need to determine how large your
grid should be. Your grid should be large enough to fit all points on the grid, without any
extra spaces on the edge (the border). You will return a single string that contains your
grid. For spaces that do not have a value, you must print “_”, which will never be a
character for your grid.
Note: the command to create a new line in a string is ‘\n’. So your code should contain
‘\n’ to designate one y axis from another.

Any help is much appreciated, I've been staring at this for hours now.

Comment: With ASCII graph they mean: just printing out characters, e.g. spaces and asterisks. Please state the concrete questions you have. Please try to write some minimal code that does 'something'.

Comment: I think the text "the command to create a new line in a string is ‘\n’" must be terrible confusing for a new programmer. They want you to make a very long string; each horizontal row of the scatterplot are lots of characters like '_' and '+'. To separate the rows, where one row ends and the next starts, you have to put a '\n'.